# Creating mutiple tables from a dataframe using one constant variable against all other variables

Tags: r, dataframe, iteration

I would like to implement some kind of a loop to tabulate all variables from a dataframe against a constant, the constant being another variable.

For example, let's say I have a dataframe with 3 variables such as the dummy data below and I want to produce the tables given.

```
df <- data.frame(V1 = factor(c("L", "L", "XL", "M", "S", "XXL")),
                 V2 = factor(c("Tall", "Medium", "Tall", "Small", "Small", "Very Tall")),
                 V3 = factor(c("Vegan", "Vegetarian", "Non-V", "Vegan", "Non-V", "Non-V")))

attach(df)

table(V3, V3)
table(V3, V2)
table(V3, V1)
```

My aim is to create each individual table and compile them into a list. Once in a list, I can carry out calculations of interest using combinations of anonymous functions and apply family calls. However, I need to find a way to create these tables over a large dataset with many variables without the tedious work of creating each one manually.

I have tried using `lapply`, `sapply` and `for` loops but cannot seem to get a method which works for me. Is there a way to do this which creates the tables across all variables and puts them into a list?

Comment: I misread your question I think, but have provided an additional answer using `lapply`.

Comment: That method works beautifully and was just what I was looking for. I'm a little unclear about what is happening after table? I get that we are applying the table function to the subset of the df without the constant I wish to compare against. What does df[ , 1] achieve?

Comment: `df[, 1]` is the second argument to `table`, like `table(df[, 2], df[, 1])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare one variable to all other variables in a data.frame and then return a list, you could use `lapply` like this.

```
lapply(df[-1], table, df[,1])
$V2

            L M S XL XXL
  Medium    1 0 0  0   0
  Small     0 1 1  0   0
  Tall      1 0 0  1   0
  Very Tall 0 0 0  0   1

$V3

             L M S XL XXL
  Non-V      0 0 1  1   1
  Vegan      1 1 0  0   0
  Vegetarian 1 0 0  0   0
```

The `df[-1]` says all variables in df except the first one. Note the comma in `df[,1]` which  is required to return a vector rather than a single element list for use in `table`.

---

If you want to build a list of tables of non-same variable pairs (v1-v2, v1-v3, v2-v3), you can use `combn`. The simplify=FALSE argument returns a list.

```
combn(df, 2, FUN=table, simplify=FALSE)
[[1]]
     V2
V1    Medium Small Tall Very Tall
  L        1     0    1         0
  M        0     1    0         0
  S        0     1    0         0
  XL       0     0    1         0
  XXL      0     0    0         1

[[2]]
     V3
V1    Non-V Vegan Vegetarian
  L       0     1          1
  M       0     1          0
  S       1     0          0
  XL      1     0          0
  XXL     1     0          0

[[3]]
           V3
V2          Non-V Vegan Vegetarian
  Medium        0     0          1
  Small         1     1          0
  Tall          1     1          0
  Very Tall     1     0          0
```

---

If you also want to get tables of each variable by itself, then

```
lapply(1:2, function(i) combn(df, i, FUN=table, simplify=FALSE))
```

will produce a nested list of tables.

Comment: That's a nice function, thanks. Is it possible to terminate it after x amount of tables are produced? For example, if I would like it to stop once all V1 (in row) combinations are processed. I would only want tables where V1 is the row. Cheers!

Comment: For `combn`, it's easiest to compute all of the tables and then subset the list. You could do `combn(df, 2, FUN=table, simplify=FALSE)[1:2]` for the above example.

Comment: Okay. Thanks again.